# Bash print long list as columns

Tags: bash

I have an array called nameVar, looks like this: 'server1' 'server2' 'server3' 'server4'
With the following code:

```
echo "Which F5 to connect:"
for f5 in ${!nameVar[*]}
do
    printf "%4d: %s\n" $f5 ${nameVar[$f5]}
done
```

I receive a numbered list containig each item in the array.

```
0: server1
1: server2
2: server3
```

My issue is, if my array has a lot of items, the output is too long, I have to scroll up to see the beginning.

If I use \t instead of \n, the output is not pretty, due to the various lengths (eg. some has long name like server1-eastus-2021, some has short like server002).

How can I get pretty, column-like output?

```
| 0: server1     |   3: server1-eastus-2021  
| 1: server2     |   4: server5              
| 2: server3     |   5: server6
```

Comment: The `column` command. It's default on Ubuntu I think. You may need to install on other platforms.

Comment: Or loop by 2s, say `for ((i=i; i<${#nameVar[@]}; i=i+2))` and `printf "%4d: %-24s | %4d: %-24s" $((i-1)) "${nameVar[$((i-1))]}" $i" ${nameVar[i]}"` (adjust format as needed) You would need to show the filling of `nameVar`, but it appears to be an *indexed* array instead of an *associative* array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your list is a single column, you could just pipe through to `less`.

However, I believe the `pretty` look you are after can be obtained using `pr`

```
DESCRIPTION
       Paginate or columnate FILE(s) for printing.
```

If you wanted 2 or 3 columns for example, you can use

```
$ pr -2t input_file #2 columns
$ pr -3T input_file #3 columns
```

And so on.

```
$ echo "0: server1
1: server2
2: server3
3: server4
4: server5
5: server6" | pr -2T
0: server1                          3: Serer4
1: server2                          4: server5
2: server3                          5: server6
```

Or as noted by David C. Rankin and more like your expected output, you can go for an even prettier look.

```
$ .... | pr -2 -S" |   " -T
0: server1                        |       3: server4
1: server2                        |       4: server5
2: server3                        |       5: server6
```

Comment: `pr -2 -S" |   " -T` looks quite nice.

Comment: About the "less": yeah, i didnt share the whole picture, I cant use less, since after displaying this numbered list about servers, the program is asking me a number, to which server i want to ssh.

The "pr" is quite useful, thanks for pointing it to me. But I'm not sure, how to get it into the code, since it is a for cicle, when i just append at the end of the "printf ..." line, it doesnt do anything.
Also it would mean i have to know how many columns i want, so it's not dynamic...

Comment: Current code:

`#!/bin/bash

while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray
do
  nameVar+=(${myArray[0]})
  ipVar+=(${myArray[1]})
done < listfile.txt

echo "Which F5 to connect:"
for f5 in ${!nameVar[*]}
do
    printf "%4d: %s\n" $f5 ${nameVar[$f5]} | pr -3t
done

read -p "Select an F5 to connect: " CHOISE
if [ "$CHOISE" == 0 ] || [ "$CHOISE" == 1 ] || [ "$CHOISE" == 2 ] || [ "$CHOISE" == 3 ] || [ "$CHOISE" == 4 ] || [ "$CHOISE" == 5 ]
then
 read -p "Enter username: " USERNAME
else
 USERNAME='testuser'
fi`

Comment: Ok my code doesnt look very well in that comment... Sorry about that, I'm new into stackoverflow.

Comment: @GergőVadász Could a temp file be an option? e.g `printf "%4d: %s\n" $f5 ${nameVar[$f5]} > tmp.file; pr -3t tmp.file; done  `

Comment: good idea. however if i use single >, then i only see the last line in the file. If I use double >>, then imagine i would use this script multiple times a day, it would append same content a lot of times.
Is it possible to redirect that printf output into a variable which is only existing during the scipt execution? Also that would prevent the creation of this tmp file.

Comment: @GergőVadász As the original question has been addressed, please open a new question addressing the sorting needs. You could try piping the output to `sort -u` before `pr` but if this does not help, please ask a new question.

Comment: Note that `-t3` or `-t4`, etc. also work. In case you want to try changing the number a bunch of times this is easier to process via backspace